# app is not defined at client in ASP.NET Zero

Tags: javascript, referenceerror, aspnetzero

I started building an application using ASP.NET Boilerplate, and as I am getting familiar with the framework I am considering a move to the paid ASP.NET Zero version. I would like to assess the effort to migrate code, as it is a big code base. Looking at n-layers, there are some differences in backend code but still manageable. However, the challenge I feel is in the UI as ASP.NET Zero is tightly coupled with the Metronic UI, and I am utilizing Kendo UI in my application.

I tried to download a cracked ASP.NET Zero version online. I followed the instructions:

- replace the cracked file in the nuget folder.
- run yarn at root application.mvc project.

The solution and all projects build and compile fine, but I am faced with an error in the browser.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined

```
 var _tenantChangeModal = new app.ModalManager({
    viewUrl: abp.appPath + 'Account/TenantChangeModal',
    scriptUrl: abp.appPath + 'view-resources/Views/Shared/Components/TenantChange/_ChangeModal.js',
    modalClass: 'TenantChangeModal',
    modalSize: null
});
```

I am not familiar with Node.js nor Angular, I use jQuery. This might be a simple fix as I might be missing something, or a bigger thing that requires further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

`app.ModalManager` is a JavaScript class in ASP.NET Zero.

You need to bundle the JavaScript files by running `npm run create-bundles` from the root directory of your `*.Web.Mvc` project.

References:

- https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-mvc/latest/Getting-Started-Core#running-the-application
- https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-mvc/latest/Developing-Step-By-Step-Core-Creating-Opening-Person-Modal

Comment: Thanks Aaron, after creating the bundles the application is up and running.